# How to implement AsyncTask in android from different layouts & classes?

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting a JSON object from the server and i am wanting to update the UI of an layout from this (grab a part of the json and update a value from this, eg; json holds {num:1, book:2} update on UI book : 1 to book : 20

The doInBackground task is in a separate class how can i pull the results from this and pass them to my UI class?

Thank you.

*Code examples preferred*

Comment: `AsyncTask` has a `onPostExecute` method that runs on UI thread.You can use that

Comment: Show your efforts

Comment: Tell us something more about your code, is AsyncTask is in the same class? Some more information is required.

Comment: @Ramanlfc i am aware of this 'onPostExecute' however how would i in this method say that i want to edit a certain class/layout and a certain Textview for example in this class/layout?

Comment: @Ashwani no its in a different class this is why im finding it hard to allocate the change to different layouts/classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mentioned that what changes you want to do in UI, I'm giving a general method with an example of updating `textView` from AsyncTask.

There is a method `onPostExecute()`, which can help you here. Say you have an instance of textView in UI, then you can do following:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

And yes, as you are asking that your views are in different class and how to access them in AsyncTask class then here is the solution:

Pass Activity instance when you start executing AsyncTask. Now you can use all the view from that activity. For example:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    Activity mActivity;

    //constructor. 
    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
       mActivity = ativity;
    }

   ...

   protected void onPostExecute(String result){
       TextView tv = mActivity.findViewById(...);
       tv.setText(result);
   }
}
```

And start AsyncTask like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation and code snippets! very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTask has a onPostExecute method exactly for this purpose. Consider this example:

```
public class ImportantTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {

    public JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do your stuff, this is a background thread
        return someJsonObject;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(JSONObject... params) {
        JSONObject json = params[0];
        // Pass those values to your views, this is a UI thread
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate? Thank you

Comment: onProgressUpdate is only for little updates while the task is still running, for example show a loading percentage (10%...20%...) while onPostExecute is when you're completely done

Comment: onPregressUpdate is for updating any UI while running the task in background @C.SMITH

Answer (score 0):

This can help
First,Make a bean of your object

```
public class MyData{
int num;
int books;
//Add getters and setters, i am leaving it for you
}
```

**Make an interface**

```
public interface MyInterface{
public void onTaskComplete(MyData myData);//make use of your bean
}
```

**Your AsyncTask Class**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
MyInterface myInterface;
public MyAsyncTask(.../*your parameters*/,MyInterface myInterface){
this.myInterface = myInterface;
}
...
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
return jsonString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {
//parse your data
MyData myData = parse(jsonString);
myInterface.onTaskComplete(myData);
}

public MyData parse(String jsonString){
//your parsing login
}

}
```

**Your Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{
//your code logic
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
//when you are calling your asyncTask
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(/*your existing parameters*/, MainActivity.this);//pass the context of activity;
myAsyncTask.execute();
//after execution your onTaskComplete method will be called.
}

@Override
public void onTaskComplete(MyData myData){
//your task has completed
//update your UI here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can use interface for this purpose. Just construct an interface with a method that will take String as an argument, use that interface as a field in your AsyncTask class and on `onPostExecute()` method call the interface method using the field defined. Make your activities listen to that interface by accessing that field and then override the unimplemented method of the interface to get the string passed from the `onPostExecute()` method respectively.